# App gives exception on launch when added Exception Breakpoint in debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception

I am developing a Tabbar based application and on launching the app in debug mode I get the exception at the app launch.

This happened only when i add the exception breakpoint. Although I can move ahead when switching this breakpoint off and app can still run. But I wanted to figure out why this is happening.

I have attached the stack track snapshot what is seen on Thread 1 when the debugger stops.

[image: Stack trace image for the stopped debugger when adding Exception Breakpoint in Xcode]